# How to use combined primary key in multi-table query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, mysql-8.0

DDL & DML examples:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  `ID` VARCHAR(8), `yearly_return` DECIMAL(16,2)
);
INSERT INTO a
VALUES
  ('0001', 0.4), ('0002', 0);
CREATE TABLE b (
  `ID` VARCHAR(8), `drawdown` DECIMAL(16,2)
);
INSERT INTO b
VALUES
  ('0001', 0.2), ('0002', 0);
CREATE TABLE c (
  `ID` VARCHAR(8), `author` VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO c
VALUES
  ('0001', 'join'), ('0002', '');
CREATE TABLE d (
  `ID` VARCHAR(8), `date` VARCHAR(20), `yield_the_day` DECIMAL(16,2)
);
INSERT INTO d
VALUES
  ('0001','20220910', 0.02), ('0001','20220911', 0.06);
```

mysql: 8.0.26

**Background**: id (0001) is the primary key in tables a, b, c, and id and date (0001, 20220912) are combined primary keys in table d

**Question**: How to query abcd, the result set is e. And the latest record in d needs the latest date

**Try steps:**

```
SELECT
    a.yearly_return,
    b.drawdown,
    c.author,
    
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN b test ON a.id = b.id
    INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```

Comment: There are 2 rows in `d`. You select the data from only one of them. Define strict criteria for this selection.

Comment: What is MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: mysql 8.0.26@FanoFN

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). paste the table data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: Should `id=0002` shown in the final result regardless of it's existence in table `d`? Or only return result for any `id` present in all tables?

Comment: There should be no id=0002 in the returned result, it should return a record with `id=0001` and the latest `date` in d.

Comment: What if `id=0002` data exists in all `a,b,c,d` tables? Should it be returned in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a lateral join, i.e. join a subquery that refers to the other tables:

```
SELECT
  a.yearly_return,
  b.drawdown,
  c.author,
  d.yield_the_day    
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.id = a.id
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT *
  FROM d
  WHERE d.id = a.id
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 1
) d
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Comment: two question:  1.maybe better to use INNER JOIN?   2.in the d statement, the a table cannot be accessed

Comment: This can be considered an inner join. Only that it doesn't occur once for the query, but once for every row. In the subquery we only consider D rows that match the A.id, so this is a form of an inner join. What does  "the a table cannot be accessed" mean? Do you get an error message? Which? The keyword `LATERAL` allows us to access A rows. This is what it is made for. Make sure it's not a typo in your real query (another table alias for instance).

Comment: thank you, it's work!    I try to `INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)  AS d ON d.id = a.id `, How is this different from yours?

Comment: Your subquery gets executed once for the query. So there is only one single row from D that you deal with, and you can only get one result row accordingly. My subquery gets executed for every row. So there is one D row I select per A row, and my query can return as many result rows as there are rows in A accordingly.